# Writing a map application that works on every mobile phone?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, google-maps-api-3

I want to write an application that plots locations on a map, preferably Google map, and people should be able use their mobile phone (BlackBerry, iPhone, and Android) to access my application from their phone. These locations will be stored in a database server, MySQL, and the  application will query the database, and plot the location on Google Map.

I started following a bread crumb trail into the intricate maze of Google Map API, but I can't find my way to any tutorial that teaches people how to start creating a mobile web-based map application. Does anyone here who can show me the right way to get started on developing a mobile web-based application with Google Map API ?

Any hints, tips, or suggestion, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at appcelerator – Titanium Mobile and phonegap. Both are based on html, js, css, titanium adds ruby and python) and are frameworks for compiling native apps.
Although you don't want to make a native app, you probably find some good resources on how to build you desired app with web standards. The docs are pretty good.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you, a quick search on google shows a lot of resources on those two framework. Definitely something worthy to read. Thank you for the tips